# How (e.g. in what order) does this code run and what does it do?

Tags: javascript

I have found this crazy javascript code.

Can someone elaborate the exact steps this code is going through and why?

```
(function a(a){
    return a;
})
(function b(b){
    return b;
})
(function c(c){
    return c;
})
(true);
```

Comment: Its just three functions and returning just true.. Thats it

Comment: I'm not. My friend gave me as a puzzle.

Comment: The tricky part of this "puzzle" are not the automatically invoked functions, but why they are called from left to right.  If you add a `console.log` statement before every return, you will see that `a` gets outputted before `b`, which gets outputted before `c`.  But how can function `a` know the input arg before function `b` returns it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- This will self-invoke `a` which is given `function` `b` as argument (since `a` is defined as a *variable* inside `a`'s local scope that will take presence over the *function* `a` which is declared in parent scope.).
- Then it will self-invoke `b` which is given `c` as as argument.
- Finally function `c` is self-invoked which returns `true` as that is given as argument.

You can look at it as a chain doing this:

```
a(var a)    // function b given as arg. When a returns b() will be invoked
   b(var b) // function c given as arg. When b returns c() will be invoked
      c(true)
```

`a` when inside the function (local scope) is a variable because `function foo(bar){}` is the same as `function(){var bar = arguments[0]}`.

The function `a` could be written like this and do the same exact thing:

```
function a(foo){
    return foo;
}
```

You can verify by doing this:

```
console.log('start');

(function a(a){
    console.log('a', typeof a);
    return a;
})
(function b(b){
    console.log('b', typeof b);
    return b;
})
(function c(c){
    console.log('c', typeof c);
    return c;
})
(true);

console.log('end');
```

**[ONLINE FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/NM2MN/)**

Console output (updated to show in FF as well <strike>use Chrome to see the function definition output</strike>):

```
> start
> a function
> b function
> c boolean
> end
```

Comment: I agree that this is the correct order of output, but how does the body of function `a` know the input arg when it clearly relies on function `b` to produce it?

Comment: @Steve functions are parsed before any execution takes place (the same reason you can call a function before or after its definition) so `b` is already defined when `a` is being called. As JS is single-threaded `a` must finish before `b` can be called as next entry at the event queue. It doesn't use the result from `b` only the definition of `b` *itself* (think `var b = someFunction`).

Comment: If you are talking about hoisting, then this does only apply to function declarations, not function expressions... and putting parentheses around a function makes it a function expression, i.e. `function a() {..}` does get hoisted, but neither `var a = function(){...}` nor `(function a() {...})` does.

Comment: @Steve they are declarations here too (not expressions) just not of the global scope (they belong to the self-invoked scope = function declarations inside a function). The parenthesis makes the *result* of that (first self-invoked) function the expression result not everything inside it (you can have a whole bio-sphere inside there of nested and chained declared functions).

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware - Thanks for clarifying... so if I understand you correctly, you are not saying that `function a` gets hoisted, but the result of it does... is that correct?

Comment: @Steve a becomes a local variable inside function a and is not related. But as a itself is given as a argument the variable a inside the scope of a will hold the very definition of the function a from the parent scope... (I hope I kept my tongue in place .. :-) ) (if I set a = null inside a, a as a function from parent scope would still work fine).

Comment: Thanks so much. Your last edit made it very clear. By using `typeof` it's easy to see that `a` is a function (`function b`) rather than then the Boolean.

Comment: I have a doubt why the parameter of function `a` is not null ,instead its of type `function `

Comment: @ArunKillu function declarations are parsed before any code is executed (also for children scopes). So when a is called with b as argument b is already defined as a function.

Comment: @ArunKillu see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/aegny/ Here you can see alert won't be called even if it's on the first line. This is because functions gets parsed first. You see at level 3 function c has an error in definition which causes break before anything is executed. This wouldn't happen if functions where parsed in local scopes (as c is local scope of b).

Comment: sir look at this `function b(b){
    console.log('b', typeof b);
    return b;
} ` this is what i get when i console the `a` which is a reference to the function b ,how this happens when i have not passed `a` as reference to b.

Comment: @ArunKillu sorry, I don't follow. Why is passing `a` as argument to `b` relevant here when you are showing `a` (`b` never gets `a` as argument, only `c` and as `b` is argument to `a` that should be correct if you are inside function `a` - and `b` isn't referencing `a` in that line - am I missing something)? (phew)

Answer (score 4):

To understand what's going on, simplify it:

```
(function a(d){
    return 5*d;
})
(2)
```

The above code, run in the console, will output `10`. What's happening is the brackets are telling the code to run immediately (it's called a self-invoking function), taking whatever follows as a parameter. So I'm creating `function a`, and immediately running it with `2` as the parameter.

The code you have is basically the same thing, but with more levels and no multiplication. All of your functions just return their parameters, and the one being passed is the boolean `true`, so the code will output `true` at the end.

Comment: Nice explanation that also helps make sense of the other answers :)

Answer (score 2):

This returns `true`.

First `function a` (bad name?) is defined which takes an argument and returns it. This function has been called immediately, with an argument which is return value of `(function b(b){ return b; })(function c(c){ return c; })(true)`. Which gets evaluated before the `a` gets called.

`(function b(b){ return b; })(function c(c){ return c; })(true)` is a similar construct, with a function `b` being defined which returns the argument it receives, and again is called immediately with similar argument and same for the third function `c`.

Answer (score 1):

The functions are executed in a top-down order. You can call a function with another function as its argument. This is fine. It keeps doing this until "true" is passed as an argument, in which case the calling chain returns "true".

```
(function a(a){       // Function a is called with function b as an argument.
    console.log('a'); // The console.log statement is executed,
    return a;         // Then function a returns b 
})                    

(function b(b){       // Function b is called with function c as an argument.
    console.log('b')  // The console.log statement is executed
    return b;         // And then function b returns c 
})

(function c(c){       // Function c is called with "true" as an argument
    console.log('c')  // The console.log statement is executed
    return c;         // And then function c returns true.
})

(true);
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If I put console.log inside of each function, the order is opposite of what you are saying. But why?

Comment: @Juno. You are absolutely right. I revised the comments to explain why this is happening. The functions are called/executed in a top-down order.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function a(a){
            alert(a);
        return a;
    })
    (function b(b){
        alert(b);
        return b;
    })
    (function c(c){
        alert(c);
        return c;
    })
    (true);
```

Its just return the next part of parameter with () symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at it.

```
(function a(a){
  return a;
})
(function b(b){
 return b;
})
(function c(c){
return c;
})
(true);
```

These are all self-invoking functions.

But the last one:

```
    (function c(c){
      return c;
    })
    (true);
```

Gets the value true passed in. So, when it returns "c" - you get true.

For the others, it just moves up as anonymous functions get passed in the value return by the function. So, a visual.

```
   (function a(a){   <-- the return of b, gets passed in here
      return a;
    })(function b(b){return b;}) <-- the return of c, gets passed in here

    (function c(c){return c;})(true);  <--- true gets passed into c.
```